# Same full bar rest in any time signature?

Tags: notation, time-signatures, rests

Can you use a full bar rest for any time signature? If you can't,  which rest would you use to cover a whole bar with a time signature of 9/4?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it works for any time sig. Think about it, if there's a rest in a bar, but no notes, it's pretty well self-explanatory.

About the only times a semibreve rest isn't used for a whole bar are 4/2 time, and shorter that 3/16 time, both quite rarely found in pieces.

As mentioned by Lawrence Payne in an answer to a similar question, it makes sense, and is technically correct, to place the rest sign centrally in the bar, rather than at the beginning, which is where a note of the same value would normally go.

Comment: Not just "makes sense", this is the *rule* for a whole-bar rest: it goes in the middle.

Comment: @BrianChandler - thanks, edited accordingly. What I meant to say was that this rule, unlike so many, makes good sense!